# Pipe output from process substitution to variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, process-substitution

I have very complicated set of commands:

```
command | ... | ... | tee >(grep -c '[^3]$') >(grep -c '[^35]$') 1>/dev/null
```

I don't want to have a temporary file to save up output, as it is pretty huge. I tried doing `>(grep -c '[^3]$' | read variable)` and `>(grep -c '[^3]$' | read variable2)` but I guess bit doesn't work because of process substitution's sub-shell invocation.

What can I do to pipe output directly to multiple variables? Is it even possible?

Right now I have this workaround:

```
var=$(command ... | ... | ... | tee >(grep -c '[^3]$') >(grep -c '[^35]$') 1>/dev/null)
var1=$(tail -1 <<< $var)
var2=$(head -1 <<< $var)
```

but I think it is clumsy and doesn't look nice. I am aware I can grep into another file but I don't like it either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried using awk instead of grep?  an awk script could easily increment two separate counters for the two different patterns, and (in the END block) output the counts to two different files (or to one file if that's more useful to you).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `awk`, instead of `tee`-ing to two grep process substitutions.  For example:

```
command | ... | ... | awk '
     /[^3]$/  { c1++; next };
     /[^35]$/ { c2++; next };
     END { print c1, c2 > counts.txt }'

read var1 var2 < counts.txt
rm counts.txt
```

If you don't want to use a temporary file, you could do it like this:

```
read var1 var2 < <(command | ... | ... | awk '
         /[^3]$/  { c1++; next };
         /[^35]$/ { c2++; next };
         END { print c1, c2 }')
```

Comment: I am sure, but that part is irrelevant. This was just a random shell script where I realized piping into two variables might be very useful. I just used it as an example.

Comment: you forgot writing awk to a file

Comment: @FedjaMladenovic yeah, my mouse wheel is wonky and randomly pastes stuff when i use it.  accidentally deleted the `> counts.txt` from the awk END block. I need a new mouse.

Comment: yeah no problem I know it's a typo

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you're sending standard output in your command chain to `/dev/null`, so youre assignation will likely be assigning a null value.  Remove that.  It looks like you're trying to capture only the first and last line of the output; this can be tricky to do in a one-liner but `awk` should be able to handle it:

```
var="$(command ... | [...] | tee [...] | awk 'NR==1{print $0} END { print $0}')"
```

However, pipes are simple creatures.  They have one input and one output.  You can't (easily) use pipes to send data into multiple places.  The closest you'll be able to get would be to use *named* pipes, which essentially are the temporary files you're trying to avoid (technically not true; FIFO queues are different from files, but I am simplifying).

Comment: About the `/dev/null`, maybe I don't get you, but I do it to "filter out" the output. So only stdout ( redirected to var) I get are from 2 `grep`s, and non from `tee`. I try to capture only the first and last line of output only because output is 2 greps, so one line is one grep and second line is other grep.

Comment: That wouldn't be necessary if you were just piping into `grep`  (`commands | grep -cE '[^3]$|[^35]$'`) (though of course the output would be commingled.  For parsing the same input data set into different result sets, I'd be inclined to use `awk` and several output files (or FIFOs).